# I need help to find out an equation about mathematic-biology for a piece of art

Tags: mathematical-biology

I am not a mathematician but I do love mathematic a lot, and many other things that I constantly connect to maths. Alas, I was away from the most beautiful form of poetry for very long in my life, coming back to study it very lately at 37 and taking class at 40. This to explain why as much I can follow the concepts and the theories (and I do put a lot of time to study it...), as much I have difficulty to write myself mathematic with my old piece of brain.

This said, here my point: I was in the last years very infatuated with biomathematic and philosophical botany. Now here is my problem: I'm working a piece of art I would like to insert inside an equation specifically on this idea as the association of mathematic and the vegetal world. This could include the work with the number phi for the repartition of the leaves around the steam. I wish very deeply I could write it myself or that I could find it alone in a book, perhaps with a nice string of probabilities but I have to admit my limits and my age. It's terribly frustrating. I care about this drawing, I want a beautiful equation, the most archetypal I can find, most probably with some integral process (the fine line surrounding the drawn parts), about the curve and its holographic projection (if you may look how I have drawn the floral arrangement, as for example). Fact is I am not looking to find "the equation of life", but one of the existing form of equations into the field of biology and mathematic.

I am not knowledgeable enough to find alone a solution but I thought one of you may be a researcher and this area of bio-mathematic, and to help me to pick the right line of maths poetry for it. I know about the Turing work and it is possibly the beginning of an answer. Whatever you would suggest would be very seriously considered and studied.

The drawing is not finish yet, it's a work in process so please forgive me also the mistakes. I hope to have your help. I would also be very happy to collect any suggestion of readings. If I may, I would only suggest when you would like to submit an idea, to not only throw the equation to me but to explain it with words. I do follow well any written parts, but I find a bit hard when it comes to me straight with the symbols. I can then work it out too with my maths teacher, whom have recommended me this website after i questioned him first.

So, here is my question, I hope to discover your imput and thank you very much for your time, kindness and attention.

Frédérique

ps: I took the picure with my phone, it's not high quality but I hope you can see well the idea. The body would be completed with the equation to create the line of a shoulder: she is not set to be flotting like this with the roots neck

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcM28.jpg)

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for an equation representing consciousness and/or life to add to your drawing? If so, I suspect you'll have better luck on Google. Here we're better at answering precise mathematical questions that don't hinge on philosophy or scientific interpretation.

Comment: lol, that would be great but despite being touch by a hint of hybris, I remain a little more humble. I'm looking for a nice equation in what we call in french bio-mathematic, preferably on a stochastic form. The fact i associate it with a state of conciousness is out of a private connection. You're up to agree or disagree and it higly disputable. if my post a bit too philosophical, regarding your comment, I should then edit it to clarify my point. For now, I wish to find a beautiful line talking to me about a string of probability into a biological form, and possibly for a vegetal

Comment: Your ability to draw is very good. I am afraid you’re going to really struggle to get a good response from this forum, sadly. I wish you luck. Maybe researching “beauty of mathematics in nature” directly could help. We here tend to talk about beautiful *pure* mathematics (even then, not very often), removed from botany and .. vegetables

Comment: it might be because I see pure beauty in pure mathematics but it is exactly what I look for, a pure line of maths. i'm sorry if I have overpassed the purpose of the site, my maths teacher recommended it to me when I submitted him the drawing asking for help. Any ideas which mathmatician I sould look for for perhaps finding what i'm looking for?

Comment: I am working on applied mathematics to biology. There are dynamical models for plant growth; see e.g. http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~volpert/plant.pdf. There are other formula in systems ecology and systems biology. How big or small would you like your equation to be? The Chemical Master Equations is an important one but it is not small. It is given by $$\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial }{{\partial t}}P(x,t) = \sum\limits_{{j = 1}}^M {{r_j}(x - {v_j})P(x - {v_j},t)\,} - \sum\limits_{{j = 1}}^M {{r_j}(x)P(x,t)}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand straight the chemical equation you wrote, I need to take time to study it but first, it is good it is long cause i need it to install the body on the drawing. I can take several equations : if I clarify their use, it would be to draw the silhouette like in a poem of Apollinaire ( https://www.pinterest.com/pin/542543086354100659/ ).

Comment: @KBS One important matter would be the distribution of the leaves around the stem because it is the way I understand the transfer of information from the smallest to the highest. I need also to work out the arrow of the bee. It is possible to introduce here to an equation but it should be then piercing. I do find the Chemical Master equation elegant and long is good, as much I can use short too. If I may ask, what would be a collection of very important equations in regard to the vegetal?

Comment: I do not much about what you are asking and I also do not understand much what you want as some of your terminology does not connect much with the scientific one. As previously said here, you will get more rational mathematical answers rather than esoteric or philosophical ones.

Comment: it's ok, I'm printing the document you gave me link. I'll find in it what I look for hopefully and thank you for your help.